# centerXAnchor is only available in iOS 9.0 or newer?

Tags: ios, swift3, nslayoutconstraint, xcode8.2

So I'm trying to add constraints programmatically:
I'm simply adding two constraints and Xcode has started to show me:

> centerXAnchor is only available in iOS 9.0 or newer

Here is my code:

```
var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

let centerImageX = imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.centerXAnchor)

let centerImageY = imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.centerYAnchor)

constraints = [centerImageX,centerImageY]

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

One thing which I want to share is probably unbelievable that couple of days back I wasn't getting any error message.

My Xcode version is `8.2.1`.

Also my deployment target is `8.0` and above. So, if anyone could tell me or can convert or translate the same code for iOS 8.0 that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same job:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: footerView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: footerView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
```